# Hover element height

Tags: css, hover, element

Please see the image attached so I can visualize it to you clearly

[image]

I have a hover category, the black bar you see is my footer.
The problem is, how can I include all those category inside my page without passing the footer?

```
#navMenu, ul, li, li li {
    margin: 0;
    pading:0;
}
#navMenu{
    width:243px;

}
#navMenu ul {
    line-height:40px;
}
#navMenu li{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    background:#6EC8F5;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    text-align:center;
    font:bold 20px/40px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#navMenu li li {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    top:13px;
    background:#CDD0D1;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;

}
#navMenu ul li a {
    width: 240px;
    height:25px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font: 16px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    padding:0 0 5px;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top:30px;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
}

#navMenu li:hover {
    background-color:#6EC8F5;
}
#navMenu ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#6EC8F5;
}
#navMenu a:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}

<div id="navMenu">
<ul >
<li class=index_latest>Category
    <ul>
    <li><a href='../index.php?category=Blogging'>Blogging</a></li>
    <li><a href='../index.php?category=General'>General</a></li>
    <li><a href='../index.php?category=Arts and Entertainment'>Arts and Entertainment</a></li>
    <li><a href='../index.php?category=Automotive'>Automotive</a></li>                  
    <li><a href='../index.php?category=Travel and Leisure'>Travel and Leisure</a></li>
    <li><a href='../index.php?category=Womens Interests'>Womens Interests</a></li>
    <li><a href='../index.php?category=Writing and Speaking'>Writing and Speaking</a></li>
    </ul>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

UPDATED:
I wanted to divide my list into half so i can display the 1st and 2nd half side-by-side

Comment: @prash what code do you need? the CSS?

Comment: @IvorySantos the HTML and CSS of the menu and nothing but the menu. We don't want your whole page, just what is necessary to work with the menu. Putting something up on [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/) would be best.

Comment: @Ivory Santos put some code,otherwise we can only guess your problem.

Comment: @prash code is there now

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to add more members to that list

1. add "min-height" to your body tag
2. do not use top:??px attribute for footer
3. make sure you do not use any other vertical positioning for footer

If you are going to add more members to that list

1. use javascript for dynamically calculating height of each member
2. add all of these to footer height and other headers you are using
3. use this as min-height or height for body
4. try using jQuery for faster implementation, later translate the code if you are using your own library

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help without code, but the idea is simple:

Put a fixed height on the menu container and set it's overflow property to auto. Now when the user hovers over to view the menu, they'll see a scrollable list instead of it running down the page.

```
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    height: 100px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

You can (should) change the `100px` to something that makes more sense for your page.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/evikon/1)

Comment: it works. but still there is a big white space after my footer

Comment: Then you need to either make it smaller, or make it so it shows up above the button instead of below it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position to absolute, then position it above the origin by a distance equal to half of the list's total height. You'll just need need to know how tall it is. I think you can do this with the bottom property: set it to the distance you want the list to go up, and don't forget to set position:absolute.
EDIT: disregard this, I made a mistake.

Comment: If the menu is too long or the page too short some parts of the menu will be inaccessible. What if my window isn't maximized?

Comment: I messed that up; it should be set to 0 regardless of height. If you're concerned about the entire menu not fitting on the screen though, you just need a much smaller menu. That's bad for useability even if you can sqeeze it all in.